# Why does the xtk.js nrrd loader load my file in asp.net-core local site, but not in production in Azure?

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, three.js, loader, xtk

I can load and view my .nrrd file with no problem in the development local environment in asp.net core, but when I push to Azure and view the site I get an error "Uncaught TypeError: can't access property "split", d is null parse". The network status of the file is a 200 OK.

I have the same problem when using the THREE.js NRRD loader. As it working in the ASP.NET-Core local environment, I do not think it is a mapping issue. But just in case I am using

`provider.Mappings[".nrrd"] = "application/octet-stream";`

I also used

`provider.Mappings[".nrrd"] = "text/plain";`

and they both work locally.
This leads me to think it is azure related, but I also have no idea how it is.

Any help is much obliged.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you please tell me which Azure resources you have hosted your asp.net core application? Azure web app or Azure VM?

Comment: Hi Brando Zhang, it is hosted on Azure web app.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out it was an issue with originally using git-lfs to upload my .nrrd files to github. Git-ltf uses pointers and the loaders did not work with those pointers to load my files. Furthermore, I had to remove git-lfs from the repository in the correct series of steps as it marks and tracks all my .nrrd files when I originally used it. It is likely that I had done something wrong, and the loaders could work with the correct git-lfs configuration.